# how to apply numeric validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, validation, razor

I want to apply validation for integer but it's not working

```js
function fnAllowNumeric() {
  if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && event.keyCode != 8) {
    event.keyCode = 0;
    alert("Accept only Integer..!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<td>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Items[i].ReceivedNumberOfCases, new { @class = "form-control text-right", @id="Received_"+ i ,@onkeyup = "outer.onChangeReceived("+ i +")" ,onkeypress="return fnAllowNumeric()"})
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Items[i].ReceivedNumberOfCases,null,new{@class="text-danger",@id="recivedCasesMessage_"+ i })&nbsp;

</td>
```

Comment: FYI: [`onkeypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress) is deprecated (though should still work for now)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use `onblur`:

```
<input onblur="return fnAllowNumeric(this)">
```

js:

```
function fnAllowNumeric(t) {
            if (($(t).val() < 48 || $(t).val() > 57) && $(t).val() != 8) {
                $(t).val(0)
                alert("Accept only Integer..!");
                return false;
            }
        }
```